# How do I increment a variable so it chooses differnet lines from a text files in a While Loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a script im writing. Here is whats happening. There is a while loop. In the while loop is a variable which is constant to X. How do i make X change from line one, line two, etc for each cycle of the while loop and pull X from a .txt file. Everything is in root. Thanks

Comment: Frankly, I have no idea what you're trying to ask. What language are you using? Are you just trying to iterate over all the lines in a text file, or what does "pull X from a .txt file" mean? What's "root"?

Comment: Could you post your script (or, preferably, a simplified version of the script that shows the problem)?

Comment: Ok while (this condition is true){

$x = next line down a txt file; 

};

its php. How do i write that

Answer (score 2):

```
$f = fopen("some.txt", "r");
while (!feof($f) && $some_condition) {
    $x = fgets($f);
    // do something
}
fclose($f);
```

Would this be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the pseudo code captain Kirk:

```
//we assume current working directory is root
fileHandle = openFile("Read","some.txt");
X = pull("X",fileHandle);

while( X is constant )
{
  XFactor = factor(X);
}
```

I can refine and improve this with more details about what universe you are from, the programming language you intend to use, and more specifics about what you want to happen.

Comment: I feel kind of bad for voting this up, but I laughed out loud.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get the lines of the file into an array
$file_array = file($file_name);

//go through the array line by line
foreach ($file_array as $line_number => $line)
{
  //you didn't tell us what you are doing with each line
  //so you will need to change this to your liking
  $X = $line; // Handle the line
}
```

Edit: Note for very large files this may not be a good approach because this will load the entire file into memory at one time.